# Image maps in iPhone app

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, iphone

I want to impliment a clickable pie chart in iphone app. I have an image for this but i want to know how can i specify clickable areas using UIImageView or any other component. I don't want to use HTML image map.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be to add transparent buttons on top of your image.

```
UIButton *transparantButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
transparantButton.frame  = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50);
[transparantButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[imageView addSubview:transparantButton];
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! Can i specify a button in any shape? For example i have a pie chart image. Now with the above solution can i specify a button to take shape of a pie or any irregular shape for that matter?

Comment: OK - I think I understand your question better now. You want to be able to have non-rect touch areas. You could either stack many rectangle buttons to approximate your area (nasty!!) or extend your imageView to override the touchesBegan function - here you could algorithmically determine which section of the pie chart has been clicked on. If you'd like a code example, let me know and I'll try and rustle something up! N

Comment: The first option sounds a little nasty for a beginner like me! For the second one, i am really starting to wonder how it could be achieved byoverriding imageView. I am just starting to think that implementing it through UIWebView using the HTML could be a faster option. I am short on time really. Your thoughts on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can probable try by placing custom buttons over the areas you want or detect touch and based on the location of touch u can perform necessary actions.

Note: The method using buttons is better if the number of such clickable regions is small.

Comment: Can i specify a button in any shape? For example i have a pie chart image. Now with the above solution can i specify a button to take shape of a pie or any irregular shape for that matter?

Comment: I dont know if it helps but you can have an idea about it http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html

Answer (score -2):

you can create image map for iphone using jquery mobilymap: [Jquery Map](http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-map/demo.html)

Comment: He does not want to use HTML.